# Is there a way to calculate the row from the previous row only if the name is the same, in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

Two rows have to be checked (name) whether they are identical and then calculated (diff previous day = day earn - previous row "day earn"). If not identical, the value will be taken over without calculating. Hope I explained correctly, see pic to better understand. Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DPOQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using power query

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\anumua2\Downloads\im_19_oct_1.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), "Date", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Date.1", "Date.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Date.1", type text}, {"Date.2", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Prev" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[#"day earn"]),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(Prev, {{"Custom", 0}}),
    #"Prev name" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Errors", "Previous Name", each #"Replaced Errors"{[Index]-1}[#"Name"]),
    #"Replaced Errors1" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Prev name", {{"Previous Name", ""}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Errors1", "Custom.1", each if([Name] = [Previous Name]) then [day earn] - [Custom]
else [day earn])
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: If this answer is useful to you, accept the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer and solution! It works, but it takes a lot of resources. More than 20 minutes to create model for a source (.txt) with around 26K rows by 10 columns. Maybe another idea how to solve it differently?